# おみくじアプリをDartで作成しているがおみくじの結果が表示されない

Tags: flutter, dart

おみくじアプリをDart（Flutter）で作成しようとしたところ、画面1のように構文？が表示されておみくじの結果が表示されません。

このコードで組んでみたものの、結果は一切表示されず　画面2のように時折赤い画面が表示されます。
List内に入力した文字列をランダムに抽出するにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

**画面1**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**画面2**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**現状のコード:**

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FortunePage(),
    );
  }
}

class FortunePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FortunePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<FortunePage> createState() => _FortunePageState();
}

class _FortunePageState extends State<FortunePage> {
  
  List<String> omikujis =['大吉','吉','中吉','小吉','末吉','凶','大凶'];

  List<String> results = ['大吉','吉','中吉','小吉','末吉','凶','大凶'];


  void drawOmikujis(String drawOmikujis){
    omikujis = drawOmikujis as List<String>;
    you_Result();
    setState(() {});

  }

  void you_Result(){
    final randomResult = Random().nextInt(6);

    results = randomResultToOmikuji(randomNumber) as List<String>;

  }

  String randomResultToOmikuji(int randomNumber){
    switch (randomNumber) {
      case 0:
        return '大吉';
      case 1:
        return '吉';
      case 2:
        return '中吉';
      case 3:
        return '小吉';
      case 4:
       return '末吉';
      case 5:
       return '凶';
      case 6:
       return '大凶';
      default:
       return 'おみくじを引いてください';
    }
  }


  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        
        title: Text('ギャラクシー占い'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              randomNumberToResult.toString(),

              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 32,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 48,),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print(randomNumberToResult);
              },
              child: Text('おみくじを引く'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```